# How to have multiple font-icons in one data-icon declaration or div

Tags: html, css

Using font icons I put

```
<div data-icon="r"> </div>
```

to have an icon display for example.

Now if I like two or more of the same icon to display next to the first one can I only use multiple divs for that like so

```
<div data-icon="r"> </div>
<div data-icon="r"> </div>
<div data-icon="r"> </div>
```

or can one somehow write

```
<div data-icon="r" "r" "r"> </div>
```

or

```
<div data-icon="r,r,r,r"> </div>
```

or something along those lines?

Naturally all these tests fails so I wonder if this is generally possible in HTML and if so how please?

Comment: What about `<div data-icon="r r r r"> </div>`? However, my guess is that it's not possible given my suspicions about how the icon system works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
<div>
    <i data-icon="r"></i>
    <i data-icon="r"></i>
    <i data-icon="r"></i>
    <i data-icon="r"></i>
</div>
```

This should create 4 inline icons. Im basing this on how font awesome works.